# Do i need application ID for Chromecast remote view playback?

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromecast

I'm developing video player app. I have to cast with Chromecast device. So I did sample app Guidance by
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender

Here I didn't get cast button on top of the action bar, any ideas why?

I don't need custom receiver, so do I need Application ID or can I use `CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID`?

Comment: If you plan on using a default receiver, you can just use the ID you mentioned. Did you follow all of the steps in the "Adding the Cast Button" section? Were there any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a receiver on a cast device, you have an option of using the default receiver, which corresponds to the app id you had mentioned. However, you will not be able to debug your receiver; if you want to debug your receiver, you need to use either a Styled Receiver or you can write a custom receiver; for both of those options, you would need to register an obtain an app id. Note that the title of your post is somewhat misleading; there is Remote Display that has been added recently (basically you create a view in your app on your android device and instruct the system to render that on a cast device) so I suggest you update that for others to find the right post.